# DXA .NET 1.4, error with script ttm-prepare.ps1

Tags: web8, dxa, dxa-1.4

I started the DXA install following the steps from [the documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v4&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA) but got stuck with the following error. I however proceeded with next step to import and that worked fine.

I get a rather strange error which says it cannot convert `System.Object[]` to the type `System.String`?

I looked into the script, it is trying to split the `baseUrls`. Is it expecting more URLs here? I tried comma separated -> `dxastaging, dxalive` and `http://dxastatging, http://dxalive`  etc. but it didn't work.

```
do { $baseUrls = Read-Host "Enter DXA '$($cdEnvironment.EnvironmentPurpose)' Website Base URL(s)" }
            until ($baseUrls)
            $baseUrls = $baseUrls.Split(",")
            $website = Add-TtmWebsite -CdEnvironmentId $cdEnvironment.Id -BaseUrls $baseUrls -ErrorVariable cmdletError
```

Error message:

```
PS E:\sw\Tridion\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\cms> .\ttm-prepare.ps1
Enter DXA 'Staging Staging' Website Base URL(s): dxastaging
Add-TtmWebsite : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'CdEnvironmentId'.
Specified method is not supported.
At E:\sw\Tridion\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\cms\ttm-prepare.ps1:112 char:56
+             $website = Add-TtmWebsite -CdEnvironmentId $cdEnvironment.Id -BaseUr ...
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-TtmWebsite], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.AddWebsiteCommand

Website registered with Id '' and Base URL(s): dxastaging
Please provide information for the 'Live' CD Environment:
        Enter Discovery Service URL (leave empty if you don't want to configure it): http://10.177.4.83:8082/discovery.s
vc
        Enter OAuth Client ID (leave empty if OAuth is not used):
Add-TtmCdEnvironment : Property 'DiscoveryEndpointUrl' of the item of type 'CdEnvironmentData' must be unique. Source
of conflict: 'CdEnvironment2'.
At E:\sw\Tridion\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\cms\ttm-prepare.ps1:78 char:34
+                 $cdEnvironment = Add-TtmCdEnvironment `
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...ironmentCommand:AddCdEnvironmentCommand) [Add-TtmCdEnvi
   ronment], DataServiceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.AddCdEnvironmentCommand

        Enter Discovery Service URL (leave empty if you don't want to configure it):
Applying Site Type Keys 'DxaSiteType' and 'DxaExampleSite' to DXA Web Applications:
Add-TtmSiteTypeKey : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'WebApplicationIds' because it is null.
At E:\sw\Tridion\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\cms\ttm-prepare.ps1:144 char:93
+ ... ApplicationIds $stagingDxaWebAppIds | Out-Null
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-TtmSiteTypeKey], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.Cmdlet
   s.AddSiteTypeKeyCommand

Add-TtmSiteTypeKey : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'WebApplicationIds' because it is null.
At E:\sw\Tridion\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\cms\ttm-prepare.ps1:145 char:96
+ ... ApplicationIds $stagingDxaWebAppIds | Out-Null
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-TtmSiteTypeKey], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.Cmdlet
   s.AddSiteTypeKeyCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the PowerShell error message, the problem seems to be in the `CdEnvironmentId` parameter of the `Add-TtmWebsite` command. So, in the value of `$cdEnvironment.Id`.
Does your CD Environment ID contain a comma? PowerShell may then misinterpret it as an array of strings instead of a single string.

I did notice that your CD Environment has a quite remarkable purpose "Staging Staging" (what's wrong with just "Staging" ? :-) So maybe it also has a weird ID?

Comment: how can I check my CdEnvironmentId? Most probably I should not have put a comma there. I guess the purpose name "Staging Staging" is pointing to some issue, coz I did not put that name there. 

Please mind that this is a completely new Web 8 setup that I am doing along with new DXA setup also that I am doing this for the first time.

Comment: Run `Get-TtmCdEnvironment` to see all the CD Environments (incl. their ID and EnvironmentPurpose) that are defined in TopologyManager.

Comment: Thanks, I get 2 EnvironmentPurposes, both Staging (one for topology DxaStagingOnly with Id CdEnvironment2 and the other one for visitorsweb with Id SampleCD)
I removed CdEnvironment2 and for that I had to remove DxaStagingOnly also. After this ran the .\ttm-prepare.ps1 script which worked.

Comment: The 2 EnvironmentPurposes I got:
EnvironmentPurpose   : Staging
DiscoveryEndpointUrl : http://10.177.4.83:8082/discovery.svc
Credentials          : "AuthenticationType":"Anonymous"
IsOffline            : False
ScopedRepositoryKeys : {}
Id                   : CdEnvironment2
ExtensionProperties  : {}

EnvironmentPurpose   : Staging
DiscoveryEndpointUrl : http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc
Credentials          : "AuthenticationType":"OAuth", "ClientId":"registration", "ClientSecret":"********"
IsOffline            : False
ScopedRepositoryKeys : {}
Id                   : SampleCD

Comment: Hmmm... it seems the script got confused by the fact that you had two CD Environments with purpose Staging, then (that is a way of saying that you uncovered a bug :-).  That explains the weird purpose and the error message: `$cdEnvironment` is supposed to be a single CD Environment, but in your case became an array of two (both with purpose Staging).

Answer (score 1):

A Base URL should be a valid URL, so not `dxastaging` (which is a host or domain name), but `http://dxastaging`, or `http://localhost`, or `http://staging.site.com` (including port if not 80).

If you want to provide multiple Base URLs, then separate them with a comma, not a comma and a space, so `http://dxastaging,http://dxalive`.

I agree that this information should be added to the documentation, since currently it only states you should run the script.

Comment: I tried again without the space but I still get the same error. Do I need create these URLs as websites in IIS before I use them here? I haven't done that till now. I am trying to follow the steps mentioned in the documentation.

@Rick, how can I check my CdEnvironmentId? Most probably I should not have put a comma there. 
I guess the purpose name "Staging Staging" is pointing to some issue, coz I did not put that name there.

Please mind that this is a completely new Web 8 setup that I am doing along with new DXA setup also that I am doing this for the first time.

Comment: Thanks Bart, I did get through the ttm-prepare command but now when I publish, I do not see anything in the publishing queue? I guess removing DxaStagingOnly purpose is causing this.